# MS excel Vb.net ui

Tags: vb.net, excel, vba

I am new in excel vb.net programming. I am building a excel add-in like the image attached. I have searched but did not find a way to create its UI like the attached image. Please let me know if its possible or not, if yes, please provide me the links.

Thank you so much

[image]

Comment: What you want is to customize the Ribbons in Microsoft Excel/Office application. Office allows you to add custom buttons to its ribbons

Answer (score 2):

You can easily add your own buttons, graphics to Excel or any Office product (Word/Power Point/Excel/ etc) by simply right clicking the ribbon area, then choosing [Customize the Ribbon].

In the next window, if you want your buttons to be displayed on their own Ribbon, create a new Ribbon.

Add as many buttons as you want, and you can separate them if you like.

[image: Customizing Ribbons in Excel]

You can read more about Customizing Ribbons in Office products [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Customize-the-ribbon-3c610b47-6f0f-4179-83d3-68a254a80ea6).

Comment: Thank you very much, can you please provide me some link so I can read VBA language

Answer (score -1):

You can create a new tab on your ribbon as Ahmad has mentioned. You can then add buttons to your new ribbon tab and have them execute macros that you have written. For example, if while working in Excel, you have to highlight cells often with yellow, you can write a macro in your personal workbook then have a button in your new tab execute that macro.